# How do I get a handle on deep stacks of functors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, nested, functor

Now and then I find myself mapping over a deep stack of functors, e.g. a parser for some collection of optional values:

```
-- parse a rectangular block of characters to a map of
-- coordinate to the character, or Nothing for whitespace
parseRectangle :: Parser (Map (Int, Int) (Maybe Char))

data Class = Letter | Digit | Other

classify :: Char -> Class

parseClassifiedRectangle :: Parser (Map (Int, Int) (Maybe Class))
parseClassifiedRectangle = fmap (fmap (fmap classify)) parseRectangle
```

What are some good ways around the nested `fmap`s? Oftentimes it's not as clear as here, and I end up adding `fmap`s until the code type checks. Simple code ends up as a mess of `fmap` boilerplate, where what I really want to express is "lift this function to the appropriate depth and apply it to the contained type".

Some ideas, none of which I've found particularly satisfactory so far:

- define `fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> g (f a) -> g (f b)` and friends
- define concrete helpers, like `mapMaybeMap :: (a -> b) -> Map k (Maybe a) -> Map k (Maybe b)`
- introduce `newtype` wrappers for the functor stack, and make those instances of `Functor`, like `newtype MaybeMapParser a = Parser (Map (Int, Int) (Maybe a))`

Do others run into this problem in large codebases? Is it even a problem? How do you deal with it?

Comment: I worry that the question is so general that it's not answerable. I can think of at least three possible approaches off the top of my head, each appropriate in different situations, and I expect with some effort I could come up with a dozen more -- with nowhere near enough detail in the question itself to choose between them. Listing them all would be a hopeless and neverending task.

Comment: You might want to check out [`Data.Functor.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) as an option. It tends to just shift the complexity from the `fmap` to the target value, though. `fmap classify (Compose . Compose $ parseRectangle)`, and the result will be wrapped in two layers of a newtype that you'd have to strip (though maybe not immediately) with `getCompose . getCompose`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, can you think of a way to make the question more specific so that it would be answerable in your view? Honestly, I imagine this is a problem many people have so listing some solutions and their pros/cons might be extremely helpful.

Comment: @robx This is all very subjective, but I think a problem with `parseRectangle` is that it returns a half-digested thing: a map corresponding to positions in some board, but still containing chars from the original text.

I would perhaps let `parseRectangle` take the classifier as a parameter, and make it return the "fully converted" data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me break the ice on this interesting question that people seem shy about answering. This question probably comes down to more of a matter of style than anything, hence the lack of answers.

My approach would be something like the following:

```
parseClassifiedRectangle :: Parser (Map (Int, Int) (Maybe Class))
parseClassifiedRectangle = doClassify <$> parseRectangle
  where
    doClassify = Map.map (fmap classify)
```

I try to use `<$>` for the top level Functor, and save `fmap` for interior functors; although that doesn't always work too well in practice.

I've used a local named binding. But even if `doClassify` were left as `f` it sometimes helps clarify a high level view of whats happening: "on the parsed value we are doing a thing, see below for what thing does." I don't know what the efficiency concerns are for making a binding.

I've also used the specific instance of `fmap` for the Map instance. This helps orient me within the stack and gives a signpost for the final `fmap`.

Hope this helps.